# Evaluating Fourier transform of $ f(t) = \sinh ^{-q}(a t) \left(1-\frac{1-a t \coth (a t)}{B}\right) $

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, mathematics

I am interested in evaluating Fourier transform of the following function analytically,

$$f(t) = \sinh ^{-q}(a t) \left(1-\frac{1-a t \coth (a t)}{B}\right) $$

where $a, B, q$ are some real parameters and  $B >> 1$, so one can neglect the second term inside the bracket to leading order.

I tried in Mathematica and also the contour integral of the complexified version without any success.

Comment: Woulf [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

In my notes I have the  following integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ikx} {\rm sech}^\nu(x) \,dx=2^{\nu-1} \frac{1}{\Gamma(\nu)} \Gamma\left(\frac \nu 2+\frac{ik}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac \nu 2-\frac{ik}{2}\right).
$$
Of course you want the same thing with a ${\rm cosech}^{\nu}(x)$, rather than the ${\rm sech}(x)= 1/{\rm cosh}(x)$.
I'm not sure where I got this  from. The Bateman manuscript table of Fourier transforms perhaps ---  but it shows that there is a good chance that these things are out there.

Comment: Perhaps more appropriate as a comment?

Comment: Thanks for the formula, but actually I want to systematically derive the answer, with the 'correction term', if possible..